# How we can use shortCuts for Emoji by Using AngularJs and Emoji.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, emoji

Here is the code which one I am using to display the emoji using AngularJS.

```
<!doctype>
<html ng-app = "app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="emoji/emoji.min.css">
  <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="emoji/emoji.min.js"></script>
  <script src="emoji/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script>
           var app =  angular.module("app", ['emoji', 'ngSanitize']);
            app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
                    $scope.message = "String including Emoji codes :smiley::eight::ear:";
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <textarea ng-model="message"></textarea>
        <p ng-bind-html = "message | emoji"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the Output [image]is like this:

But I want to add shortcut of emoji and emoji should come in output, like this:

[image]

Can anybody tell me how can I do this?